# How to stop a starting spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to stop a spring boot application while it's spinning up?

My software needs to validate a license while starting. If the license does not exist or is not valid the app shall shutdown. The actual validation happens in the `@PostConstruct` of an `@Service`.

The way I currently go is:

```
if (!exist || !valid) {
    System.exit(1);
}
```

But this solution just feels horrible. Is there a solution I can stop the spring boot application without calling a REST endpoint?

Comment: That works as it should I suspect. Before `System.exit` you could close the `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: Why not do this validation in your `main` method?

Comment: As @M.Deinum was stating: you should close the `ApplicationContext` which you should be able to do to make your License-`@Service` implementing `ApplicationContextAware` or just `@Autowire`ing your `ApplicationContext`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your code is in a component (or otherwise Spring detected bean). You can simply inject the `ApplicationContext` and before exiting call `close` on it.

```
public class LicenseChecker {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    public void check() {
        if (!exist || !valid) {
            ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) ctx).close();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems that we gave a similar answer excatly the same time. ;-) I'll remove mine to minimize confusion.

Comment: Shouldn't you be refreshing the context before close? 
Change - 
            ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) ctx).refresh();
            ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) ctx).close();
            System.exit(1);

Answer (score -2):

You can use "shutdown" endpoint to shutdown your application.

```
@Component
public class LicenseChecker implements CommandLineRunner{

  @Autowired
  ShutdownEndpoint shutdownEndpoint;

  @Override
  public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Checking License ");

    if(!checkLicense()){
      System.out.println("Shutting down application");
      shutdownEndpoint.invoke();
    }
  }

  private boolean checkLicense(){
    // check license
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: You can simply inject the `ShutdownEndpoint` and execute it, no need to do a rest call. But that would require that it is available which doesn't have to be at that point.